# symlink inside public folder to access private folder

Tags: permissions, symbolic-link

I have a shared linux machine with `user/public/` and `user/private/` folders. I have a subfolder or 2 inside private that need to stay in private. For example, I might have `user/private/projects/project1/` as a folder where I need project` to be visible. I realize I can't give someone access to project1 and let them navigate through it.

Is is possible to place a symlink in the public folder that goes directly to the subfolder I want to give access to so that it's not taking double the space on the hard drive and I don't have to update 2 folders? If not, is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Provided all folders in the private path have the "executable" bit set for "others", anyone will be able to navigate into that "project1" folder through the symlink, placed in a public folder. The permissions of the "symlink" are these of the target, i.e., your "project1" folder, so there, you will need to set proper owners and permissions on that folder so people you want can do what you want them to do.

Comment: Does this create other issues? I have a lot of, understandably, private info that I would rather not give out access to under the private path that I don't want people to be able to run (although this is not an issue for the most part as my understanding is that they would have to guess the filename).I'm unclear on whether giving execute permission allows `cd` permissions, but this is certainly something I do not want to give. Would it be better to place the folder in the public folder and then create a symlink in the private?